# how to switch from pandas.Series.from_csv to pandas.read_csv for the csv without header row?

Tags: python, pandas

`pandas.Series.from_csv` is deprecated (since 0.21 version).
I want to change my code to use `pandas.read_csv`.
However, I simply can't find variant to load the same data for a csv file without a header line.

For example, let's assume following csv:

```
cntry,country
ctr,center
hts,heights
ft,fort
mt,mount
spg,springs
spgs,springs
st,saint
ter,terrace
e,east
w,west
s,south
n,north
```

Following deprecated code:

```py
z1 = pd.Series.from_csv('file.csv')
type(z1)
z1.shape
z1
```

Gives me (executed in notebook):

```
pandas.core.series.Series
(13,)
cntry    country
ctr       center
hts      heights
ft          fort
mt         mount
spg      springs
spgs     springs
st         saint
ter      terrace
e           east
w           west
s          south
n          north
dtype: object
```

And I can't get the same result using `pandas.read_csv` and combinations of:

- `index_col=0`;
- `header=None`;
- `parse_dates=True`;
- `squeeze=True`.

For instance:

```py
z2 = pd.read_csv('file.csv',index_col=0,header=None,parse_dates=True,squeeze=True)
type(z2)
z2.shape
z2
```

gives me:

```
pandas.core.series.Series
(13,)
0
cntry    country
ctr       center
hts      heights
ft          fort
mt         mount
spg      springs
spgs     springs
st         saint
ter      terrace
e           east
w           west
s          south
n          north
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

The difference in `0`. Which isn't shown among `.values` or `.iteritems()`. Nonetheless, I don't understand what is it, and how to eliminate it using `pandas.read_csv` and its parameters.

UPDATE

`0` - is the index's title. Can be removed with: `.rename_axis(index=None)`.

`1` - is the series title. Can be removed with: `.rename()`.

And I can't see so far how to do it using `pandas.read_csv`.

Comment: ermm.. the 0 is also in the pd.series.from_csv example?

Comment: `0` is the name of the index and the name of the series is `1`, you can pass `rename_axis(None)` if you dont want the index name

Comment: @ChristianSloper wrong copy / paste for pandas.Series.from_csv, I fixed it now. There is no `0`.

Comment: @anky_91 yes, it works, and I can remove name of series ('1') with `.rename()`. Or leave both if it's just titles. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```py
z1 = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, names=['', 'values'], index_col=0)['values']
```

This will read the file into a dataframe, setting the first column as the index, then select the second column (named "values") as a series.

The only difference from your example is that the name of the series will be "values". You can always run `z1.name = None` if that is not desirable.

Comment: Right, names work. Though, in my example I'll use it as following: `pd.read_csv('file.csv',index_col=0,header=None,names=['',None],squeeze=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Using the provided solution almost worked, but for me the index was a datetimeindex, and I had a NaT value at the beggining. The workaround:

```
def load_pandas_series(filename):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0, names=['', 'values'],
                    header=None, parse_dates=True)['values']
    df1.name = None
    df1 = df1[~df1.index.isnull()]
    return df1
```